# How can I create a 2D camera for a multiplayer-game?

Tags: c#, xna, camera, 2d, multiplayer

pretty new to this site so bear with me.

Wanting to create a networked multiplayer game I'm thinking of whether to have 2D or 3D graphics, my issue is this; 
I know how to create a camera and move it around for my localplayer (and thus not affecting the other players) in a 3D world, I cannot however figure out how to do it in a 2D world without affecting the objects.

I have read on previously answered questions about 2D camera and noticed that their way to solve the way is to move the objects depending on the camera locations (thus affecting their coordinates).

During a game I plan to send and receive player coordinates continuously:

```
Move my local player
Receive other player from network and update their local coordinates
```

I dislike the previously mentioned solution since that would mean a lot of extra work translating their coordinates (that would be their local coordinates in their world) into coordinates in my local world.

I feel like it'd be worth trying to find a "simple" solution for this instead of just using the 3D-version. (Might do that later tho)
Any tips or aid/solution to my problem?
Everything's appreciated!

Comment: Check out this tutorial - http://roundcrisis.com/2012/04/19/xna-a-simple-2d-camera/

Comment: Thanks, that'll probably fix my issue!

Comment: If you've accepted my answer as the best one could you possibly up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at the ["Going Beyond: XNA Game Studio in 3D"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) tutorial offered by Microsoft as it discusses and looks at how to develop a multi-player based game with aspects of both 2D and 3D. However I don't believe it will give you all the answers you're looking for but will help you in understanding how to produce a solution for your intended goal.